# how to send action from python to a WEB interface

Tags: python

Hi guys im new to programming, hope you can help me.

I have a device that has a Web Interface.
In that Web interface it has a "Reboot button" or "link" option to reboot the device.

This is the url of the reboot button "192.10.20.55/restart.tgi",
basically when i run this in my browser the device reboot.

How can i use python to send this action to that device or to that web interface.

thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Use a [framework](https://wiki.python.org/moin/WebFrameworks). I suggest looking into [Flask](http://flask.pocoo.org/). It is a pretty neat python micro framework.

If you plan on using flask:

**server.py**:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def index():
  return render_template('template.html')

@app.route('/reload-link/')
def reload_link():
  #Do your thing here 

if __name__ == '__main__':
  app.run(debug=True)
```

**templates/template.html**:

```
<!doctype html>

<title>Test</title> 
<meta charset=utf-8> 

<a href="/reload-link/">Reload</a>
```

Run it with `python server.py` and then goto http://localhost:5000/. The development server isn't secure, so for deploying your application, look at http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/quickstart/#deploying-to-a-web-server

Comment: This is a comment not an answer.

Comment: I can't comment on the questions yet! I just wanted to help :/

Comment: I feel like you've got his question the wrong way 'round. I think he already has a web server running on his embedded device. He needs a web **client**, that can programmatically push the "reboot" button.

Comment: Oh, so you mean, calling a function from the server that would 'click' the 'reboot' button? In that case, I don't think the question has enough information :|

Comment: hi guys.. very interesting about that flask.. ill look into when i have time.  Yes, sorry about that one I edited my post. Basically i just need some direction how start this, which module or lib should i use. thank you. :D

Answer (score 0):

Start with the [`requests`](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/) library.

```
import requests
r = requests.get('192.10.20.55/restart.tgi')
if r.ok:
    print "Maybe it rebooted"
else:
    print "something is wrong!"
```